# R import data-files from ftp to dataframe

Tags: r, import, ftp

How can I import data-files from ftp to data.frame?

I use:

```
userpwd <- "user:pw"
h <- curl::new_handle()
curl::handle_setopt(
handle = h,
httpauth = 1,
userpwd = userpwd
)

resp <- curl::curl_fetch_disk("ftp://xxx/testfolder/", "test.csv", handle = h)
```

But what to do now? How can I bring the datafile from my testfolder from FTP to an R-object eg. in a dataframe? And how can I select specific data-files from testfolder?

Comment: Have you tried just passing the ftp url to the file argument in `read.table`? That function will accept urls, you can read more about it at `?read.table` and `?url`.

Comment: "read.csv("ftp://xxx/testfolder/test.csv")" brings error message: cannot open the connection to 'ftp://samsung.syzygy-server.de/www_logs/testfolder/test.csv' and cannot open URL 'ftp://xxxx/testfolder/test.csv': FTP status was '530 Not logged in'. I dont know where to place the connection to FTP in the query (I am working with R on my MAC (local)